# rhandsontable column sorting to have NAs on top

Tags: javascript, r, handsontable, rhandsontable

how do you make NAs appear on top when column sorting a rhandsontable. NA values always end up at the bottom during the sorting.

```
mtcars[1, ] <- NA
rhandsontable(mtcars) %>% 
  hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a look at the [docs](https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/api/column-sorting/) the best I could come up with is to set `sortEmptyCells = TRUE` which will still put NAs at the bottom when sorting in descending order, but vice versa will put them on the top when sorting in ascending order.

```
library(rhandsontable)

mtcars[1, ] <- NA

rhandsontable(mtcars[1:10, 1:2]) %>%
  hot_cols(
    columnSorting = list(
      sortEmptyCells = TRUE
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, is it possible to have the empty cells on top for both ascending and descending sort

Comment: As I have said, I don't see any default option to achieve that. But browsing the docs this might be possible by creating a custom [comparator](https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/rows-sorting/#add-a-custom-comparator) function to implement your desired behavior.